# Match items in list to string: How to evaluate the F1 ratio of Alchemy API NER result? Python

Tags: python

How do I match string items in list to a location on a larger string, particularly if those string items were derived from the larger string?

I currently receive my output from AlchemyAPI in this format. 
each list = Name of Entity, Count of Entity Appears in text, Entity Type, Entity Sentiment

```
[['Social Entrepreneurship', u'25', u'Organization', u'0.854779'],
 ['Skoll Centre for Social Entrepreneurship',
  u'6',
  u'Organization',
  u'0.552907'],
```

However, in order to evaluate the accuracy of this NER output, I'd like to map my alchemyAPI output of the entity type to text I already have. So for instance, if my text is the following (this is also the text I used to get my output for Alchemy API)

```
If
Social  
Entrepreneurship  
acts 
like 
This
Social 
Entrepreneurship
```

I'd like to have the fact that Social Entrepreneurship is mentioned 25 times as an ORG applied to my text. So, this would be a snippet of those 25 times.

```
If
Social  ORG 
Entrepreneurship  ORG
acts 
like 
This
Social ORG
Entrepreneurship ORG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this using a tokenizer on both the text that you're sending to the API and the returned entities to find matches.  NLTK provides that functionality out of the box with their comprehensive "word_tokenize" method (http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html) though any tokenizer will work as long as it tokenizes the entities the same as the text (ie: raw.split()).

```
# Generic tokenizer (if you don't use NLTK's)
def word_tokenize(raw):
    return raw.split()
```

With that, you would be iterating over each word (token) in the document, checking to see if you get a match the first token in the entities returned.

```
for word in word_tokenize(raw):
    for entity in entity_results:
        if word.upper() in ( ( e.upper() for e in word_tokenize(entity[0]) ):
            print(" ".join([word] + entity[1:]))
        else:
            print(word)
```

You may want to expand on this to get an exact match for the full entity, testing for the length of the token list, and testing each element by index instead.

```
words = word_tokenize(raw)
ents = [ [ e for e in word_tokenize(entity[0]) ] for entity in entity_results ]

for word_idx in range(len(words)):
    for ent in ents:
        # Check the word against the first word in the entity
        if words[word_idx].upper() in ( e[0].upper() for e in ents ):
            match = True
            # Check all words in entity
            for ent_idx in range(len(ent)):
                if ent[ent_idx] != words[word_idx + ent_idx]:
                    match = false
                    break
            if match:
                print(" ".join([words[word_idx]] + ent))
            else:
                print(words[word_idx])
        else:
            print(words[word_idx])
```

You may notice though that this prints out the full entity if it matches, it will only get you matches on the first word, and that this doesn't handle IndexError problems if the line "ent[ent_idx] != words[word_idx + ent_idx]" references an invalid index.  Some work is needed, depending on what you want to do with the output.

Finally, this all assumes that AlchemyAPI isn't including co-references in their final count.  Co-reference is when you refer to an entity using "he", "she", "it", "they", etc.  That's something you'll have to test on your own.